# need to read metadata from sharePoint is anyone help me

Tags: sharepoint-online, data

[image]need  to read metadata from sharePoint is anyone help me[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to read? Is it SharePoint list information?

Comment: we want to read entire page using rest or any using any other way... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint REST API in your client side application to read data from SharePoint list.

You have to use REST endpoint in below format:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Employee List')/items
```

**Documentation**: [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

Also, check this article [Get All Items in SharePoint using REST API](https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/get-all-items-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api). It has links to similar examples to read items using JSOM, CSOM and PowerShell which you can refer and use as per your requirements.

---

**Update**:

If you want to fetch site page contents, use endpoint in this format:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(1)?$select=Title,CanvasContent1
```

Replace `1` with the item ID of your site page from site pages library.

You can get the item ID of your site from site pages library.

1. Go to site pages library using URL like: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/SitePages`
2. Click on **Add Column** and then **Show or hide columns**:

   [image]
3. Select checkbox next to ID, click **Apply**:

   [image]
4. You will see item ID in site pages library view like:

   [image]

**OR**

You can get the page content using page name as well using API like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,CanvasContent1&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'Employee.aspx'
```

Comment: employee page details i want to read

Comment: check updated answer.

Comment: site page url not working. I have added page screenshot above please see and help how i get site ID.

Comment: Check updated answer. You can either use ID approach or get page content using page name as well. I have added both endpoints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me.