# How to retrieve the whole content of a modern SharePoint site page using the SharePoint API or Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, postman, sharepoint-page

I am currently trying to get the whole content of a modern SharePoint page using either API but I am not retrieving it successfully. So far I have tried the following:

- Calling
  `https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/{mysite}/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(x)/FieldValuesAsHtml`

Doing so depending on the page I manage to get some content in the CanvasContent1 field. But unless it is an old SharePoint page or a plain looking one, I get no relevant content here.

- Calling `https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/{mysite}/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(x)/FieldValuesAsText`

Same thing as before, although whenever I get useful information, it looks better here than with FieldValuesAsHtml, again in the field CanvasContent1.

- Attempting it with the GraphAPI calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{mysiteid}/pages/{mypageid}/webparts`

When doing this only 2 fields are received: `@odata.context` which contains a URL with an XML which doesn't solve anything for me and `value` which is always blank"[]" for me.

- Also tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{mysiteid}/pages/{mypageid}?expand=canvasLayout` but I am only getting something relevant in the description field and that is not the whole page.

I am trying all of this with Postman, I don't know if this might be relevant.

**TLDR**: What is the proper way of getting the whole content of a modern SharePoint page using either SharePoint API or Microsoft Graph API. Getting it as text/xml/html I do not care, any one works for me.

Comment: do you want to get only content (from text web parts) or you want also other information like other web part along with it's configuration?

Comment: I am only interested in content. Any text that is displayed in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below SharePoint REST API endpoint:

**Using item ID**:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(1)?$select=Title,CanvasContent1
```

**Using page name**:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,CanvasContent1&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'Employee.aspx'
```

**Similar thread**: [need to read metadata from sharePoint is anyone help me](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306427/need-to-read-metadata-from-sharepoint-is-anyone-help-me/306429#306429)

Comment: Like I said, this solution works only for simple pages that have plain text. On modern pages that have diferent boxes with information, other titles, or something more complicated, I get null in CanvasContent1 if there is no plain text.

Comment: @Smock Did you ever manage to solve it?